# How to graph a hyperbola?

Tags: graphing-functions

So this is the queation of a hyperbola: $$xy=4$$ It's not in it's standard form, how can I graph it this way?

Comment: Were you asked to tackle this without learning about $y=\dfrac 1 x$ first?

Comment: Explain it to me please :D

Comment: sorry i have used paint and  could not draw more better then this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us sketch the graph:
$$y=\frac{1}{x}$$

How does value change when $x$ changes from positive side to infinity? How does $y$ changes as $x$ changes from $0$ to negative infinity? Graph is something like this:

[image]

For positive $x$; as for negative $x$:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D1%2Fx

Check please,

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D4%2Fx